# Create a script to collect StorageAccount options in Azure

Tags: azure, shell, azure-powershell

a query can be obtained by reporting the properties (Diagnostic Settings) of the Azure Storage Account services, which are blob properties, file properties, table properties, queue properties.

What I use to get 1 for one is as follows:

```
$ storageAccountContext = (Get-AzStorageAccount -Name storage1 -ResourceGroupName rg-gruop1) .Context

Get-AzStorageServiceProperty -ServiceType Blob -Context $ storageAccountContext

Get-AzStorageServiceProperty -ServiceType File -Context $ storageAccountContext

Get-AzStorageServiceProperty -ServiceType Table -Context $ storageAccountContext

Get-AzStorageServiceProperty -ServiceType Queue -Context $ storageAccountContext
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pd5Co.jpg)

Comment: If it were possible to get all that information with a single script from all the Storage accounts and save them in CSV

Comment: just create an outer loop over this?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to get all storage accounts in your subscription, or if you want just accounts in a given resource group, you can use the *-ResourceGroupName * parameter, and then you iterate them using a simple foreach.

```
$accounts = Get-AzStorageAccount
foreach($account in $accounts){
   (...)
}
```